# Blend HTML text with canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas

I am currently rendering a canvas below some HTML elements (currently a `h1` and a `span`). The canvas contains a kaleidoscope based on an image with two major colors: one pretty dark (almost black), and one really bright, and it can be moved by moving the mouse. The HTML elements are rendered with a `color: white` style.

The problem I encounter is when the kaleidoscope renders a huge white part. The text becomes invisible. Is it possible to make the text display the negative color of the part of the canvas right under it ? So for example, if the part of the canvas under the text is white, the text would be black ? Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you compositing the text on the canvas? You might find this helpful: [Inverse text-color on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985098/html5-inverse-text-color-on-canvas).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the color to white and use css blending-mode difference:

```
h1{
  color:white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r5TMy/1/)

Comment: Thanks, that made the trick ! All I had to do was simply put the h1 in an absolute position, since the canvas already was.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use the "difference" blending mode to make the text change color:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
ctx.fillText(myText, x, y);
```

### Example

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var toggle = false;
for(var x = 0, step = c.width / 16; x < c.width; x += step) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  ctx.fillStyle = toggle ? "#000" : "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(x, 0, step, c.height);
}

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
ctx.font = "32px sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("ALTERNATING", c.width>>1, c.height>>1);
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Creative options: draw background slightly transparent to make white light-grey (setting the canvas element's CSS opacity), use shadow or outline for the text.